# How do I initialize a View which takes in a StateObject as a parameter?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
struct ProfileEditView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: UsersViewModel
    @StateObject var auth: Authenticator

    @State var showingImageEditor: Bool = false

    init(_ viewModel: UsersViewModel, _ auth: Authenticator) {
    
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.auth = auth
    
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View { }
}
```

I am trying to manually intialize a View that receives a [StateObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject) as a parameter. I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'auth' is a get-only property
```

What is the proper way to write the initializer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I can't fully reproduce your code without your definitions of `Authenticator` and `UsersViewModel`, but I got it to compile:

```
class UsersViewModel: ObservableObject {}
class Authenticator: ObservableObject {}

struct ProfileEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: UsersViewModel
    @StateObject var auth: Authenticator

    @State var showingImageEditor: Bool = false

    init(_ viewModel: ObservedObject<UsersViewModel>, _ auth: Authenticator) {

        _viewModel = viewModel
        _auth = StateObject(wrappedValue: auth)

        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("something")
    }
}
```

These are the key changes:

```
init(_ viewModel: ObservedObject<UsersViewModel>, _ auth: Authenticator) {
    _viewModel = viewModel
    _auth = StateObject(wrappedValue: auth)
```

If you don't understand my changes you should google

> "swift property wrappers"

to get a better understanding of what property wrappers are and how to use them.

Comment: This is indeed the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 'accepted answer' there's a really good example that will allow everyone to reproduce the error and understand how to avoid it.

Considering there's a `viewModel` in a `View` with a property wrapper `@StateObject`, there's no need to initiate a `StateObject(wrappedValue: ...)` in the constructor **as long as there are no private properties in the `View`**. Let's see an example:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {}

struct MyView: View {
   @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
}
```

The above example will work by simply using:

```
MyView(viewModel: MyViewModel())
```

But if we will add a private property to the `View`:

```
struct MyView: View {
   @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
   // `test` will produce the protection level error
   private var test = false
}
```

Our previous example `MyView(viewModel: MyViewModel())` will now produce the following error:

> *initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level*

So please consider why you declare a property in a `View` private, perhaps it can be moved to the `ViewModel` and the issue will be solved in order to utilize the dependency injection principle.